# Iterating through Struct MATLAB

Tags: matlab, struct, matlab-struct

Below is what I have so far. I need to iterate through each field of `rxnsBothKaletaS` struct where each field represents a `nx4` cell. I need to extract information out of the first column of that cell as a single string separated by commas and then assign it to an index of the field in `fname`.

*(To give the context: `fname` are names of the genes and within eaach gene are reactions that rely on that gene. I need to extract all of the reactions for a given gene and have them all as a string separated by commas)*

```
fname = fieldnames(rxnsBothKaletaS)
for  i = 1:numel(fname)
    gene = rxnsBothKaletaS.(fname{i})

    for j = 1:size(gene,1)
        rxns = rxns + char(string(gene(j,1)));
    end 

    fname(i,2) = rxns; 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`structfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/structfun.html) to iterate through the fields of a struct. Then within the anonymous function that we will apply to each field, we can use `strjoin` to join all strings in the first column of `x` together with commas.

```
fnames = structfun(@(x)strjoin(x(:,1), ','), rxnsBothKaletaS, 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

Comment: i get an error :



Error using strjoin (line 55)
First input must be a cell array of character arrays.

Error in model_comparison>@(x)strjoin(x(:,1),',')

Error in model_comparison (line 17)
fnames = structfun(@(x)strjoin(x(:,1), ','), rxnsBothKaletaS,
'UniformOutput', 0);

Comment: @SeanSadykoff What is inside of your `N x 4` cell array if it isn't strings?